# How to filter the list of reports which uses the specific filter condition?

Tags: salesforce, report, salesforce-lightning

I have 1000 reports in my org.
In that, I need to get the list of reports which uses Opportunity BU filed in filter condition.
Filter : Opportunity BU equals US-SI, US-DE
Opportunity BU is a pickiplist field.

Answer (score 0):

Without any special setup you could make-do by going to the field's definition and clicking "Where is this used?" button. Should list (among others) the reports. It won't be great because you have no way of checking how it's used (as filter, as column, as grouping) but it's a start. Click-click-click...

If you have a developer in the team - they could use sfdx / vscode to download all [report definitions as XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72123288/how-to-filter-the-list-of-reports-which-uses-the-specific-filter-condition) and then run some search in text files.